# Magento difference between collection and resource collection

Tags: magento

In Mage_Core_Model_Abstract there is the `getCollection` method that is widely used.

But, I had never looked at the `getCollection` method until now.  I can see that all it does is call `$this->getResourceCollection()`

What is the point in having `getCollection` and why don't everyone just use getResourceCollection instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for my point of view, it just gives me more clean code for model collection retrieval, without unnecessary typing of word Resource all the time. Also if you look into Order model or Quote model, you will see that it also using simplified method name for collection retrieval of items, addresses, payments, etc.

If it would be named `getItemResourceCollection()`, `getAddressResourceCollection()` instead of `getAddressCollection()` or `getItemsCollection()`, amount of characters you type during development is increasing. There were no explanation about why `getCollection()` should be used in favor `getResourceCollection()` while I was working in core team, but it was quite logical for me to use shorter name of method.

At least non of these methods are marked as deprecated, so you can use them both.

Comment: Just one question, in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product : the core team have overridden the getResourceCollection method, apparently only add the store id to the collection.  What would be the reasoning behind that?

Comment: If you have flat catalog enabled, Magento using different tables for each store, so it is necessary to provide store id for collection when your are using it on the frontend. Since product getStoreId() is using logic to detect current store view, with possibility to override it by setStoreId() method, it is quite logical to set this store id to collection as well, if it is retrieved from model.